# ExcelJS incorrect column count returned

Tags: typescript, exceljs

I have a excel workbook which contains multiple sheets. While parsing the xlsx file, only one the sheets returns an unexpected column count i.e expecteted count 10 actual count 16294

```
 const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

 const buffer = await data.arrayBuffer();

 const loadedWb = await workbook.xlsx.load(buffer);

 for(const worksheet of loadWb.worksheets) {
    const totalcolumns = worksheet.columns.length
 }
```

What I've tried:

- I've ensured no additional columns or rows are populated and are empty
- The file does contain data that have values derived from other cells.
- Some cells are empty within the expected row and column range
- Created a new dummy excel file and that returned all correct column counts
- The worksheet contains about 200 rows  only
- Tried looking in github issues

I haven't been able to find anything that can help me understand what is causing an incorrect number of column count to be returned. Looking for any insights.

https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs

Comment: Seems especially interesting, as the specifications for excel say, that a sheet can have a maximum of 16,384 columns ...

Comment: My bad - I made a typo in the number. I've also realised I was using worksheet.columns.length instead of worksheet.columnCount. Interestingly all sheets return the correct column length instead of one which is returns 16,294